# Call ATTR=ID:name from csv file in imacros

Tags: csv, tags, call, attr, imacros

Is it possible to call from imacro a list of names in a csv file? EXAMPLE: - TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:john, TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:mike, TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:albert ...etc I do have all the names in a csv file

Answer (score 2):

```
SET !DATASOURCE PATH_TO_YOUR_CSV_FILE\CSV_FILE_NAME.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:{{!COL1}}
```

For more, read [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/Demo-Loop-Csv-2-Web).